# EPPlus - Countifs with wild cards are not calculating when running Workbook.Calculate in EPP5

Tags: c#, excel, epplus, epplus-4

I have an excel template that I write data to using EPP5.
When I run the `ExcelPackage.Workbook.Calculate()` method no error is thrown.  When I go to open the workbook, it still needs to calculate the fields that contain `countifs` formulas with wild cards.
All of the `countifs` formulas with wildcards show as #VALUE when the workbook is opened, the excel GUI then calculates the workbook, and the correct result is then shown in the cells.  My hope is that no calculation needs to occur when the workbook is opened.

Here is an example of one of the `countifs` formulas:

```
=COUNTIFS(Q3,"*Did you mean*")
```

I have narrowed down the behaviour to any logical sum/count function using wild cards.  I am not assigning the formula through the EPPlus API which I know should not include the "=" character in the front of the formula. The formula exists natively in the excel file so the formula includes the "=" character in the cell.

Comment: I submitted a tiicket to the EPPlus team and they told me that it was a bug and something that would be resolved in path 5.2.  Stay tuned.

Answer (score 0):

This bug was fixed in release 5.5.2.